# Change HTML Form Action from 'HTTPS' to 'HTTP' with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have several forms on an HTML page that look like this:

```
<form class="pagination" action="https://www.myaction.com" method="post">
...
</form>
<form class="pagination" action="https://www.myaction.com" method="post">
...
</form>
<form class="pagination" action="https://www.myaction.com" method="post">
...
</form>
```

and I want to change the action to `http://www.myaction.com`. What is the easiest way do this?

I tried this:

```
$('.pagination').attr('action').replace('https', 'http');
```

but that didn't work. Any other simple idea's?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you are doing is changing a string, but not affecting the dom elements themselves.

Try:

```
$('.pagination').attr('action', function( _, action){
    return action.replace('https', 'http');
});
```

Using the function argument of `attr()` will loop over all matching selectors providing index and existing value as arguments.

Reference **[attr( attributeName, function )](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function)**

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form.pagination').attr('action', function() {
        return this.action.replace(/https:/i, 'http:');
    });
});
```

```js
function out( sel ) {
     $('.pagination').each(function() {
       $(sel).append( this.action + '\n' );
     });
   }


   $(document).ready(function() {
        out('.before');
        $('form.pagination').attr('action', function() {
            return this.action.replace(/https:/i, 'http:');
        });
        out('.after');
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="pagination" action="https://www.myaction.com" method="post">
...
</form>
<form class="pagination" action="https://www.myaction.com" method="post">
...
</form>
<form class="pagination" action="https://www.myaction.com" method="post">
...
</form>
<pre class="before"><h1>BEFORE</h1></pre>
<pre class="after"><h1>AFTER</h1></pre>
```

Comment: Good idea on using regex to account for case, even if it does seem a bit overkill technically.

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this:

```
$('.pagination').each(function() {
    var url = $(this).attr('action').replace('https', 'http');
    $(this).attr('action', url);
});
```

If you call attr with just one parameter, jQuery will understand you want to **read** the value. If you call it with two parameters, it'll know you want to **set** the value.

Comment: won't work if forms have different `action` values, will set them all the same as the value will come from first form encountered

Answer (score 0):

They way you did it is wrong, should be:

```
$('.pagination').attr('action', $('.pagination').attr('action').replace('https', 'http'));
```